# Из чего состоит цикл?

Tags: циклы, любой-язык

Мне чисто из любопытства интересно как же в любом языке программирования сделан цикл: `for, while, repeat, foreach` и т.д.

Сам уже часто юзаю, но если бы хотел написать свой язык, столкнулся бы с проблемой, а юзать чужие библиотеки хочется по-минимуму, для накопления знаний.

*Так из чего состоит цикл, как он взаимодействует с компьютером?*

Вот я понимаю как цикл работает, *но как же он дает команду процессору - вернись и повтори еще раз?*

Comment: чтобы узнать лучше как это работает, лучше заглянуть в ассемблер: http://natalia.appmat.ru/c&c++/assembler.html Там небольшая лекция, про регистры, а также есть ответ на вопрос - 4. Переходы и циклы

Comment: Для осознания можно написать цикл на Ассемблере

Comment: Любой цикл можно реализовать с помощью goto — такая команда у процессора есть (в случае x86 это вроде инструкция JMP)

Comment: @andreymal а `goto` разве не умирающая тема во всех языках практически?

Comment: @VladSpirin в процессорах — точно не умирающая, а про языки я ничего не говорил

Comment: Понятно,а можно рассшифровать что такое JMP?

Comment: @GGO подробности есть по ссылке из ответа

Comment: @ggo Если кратко, то программа выполняемая процессором в виде двоичных кодов лежит в памяти и для каждой инструкции известен точный адрес в памяти, по которому она лежит. И есть команды переходов по указанному адресу. С помощью таких переходов работают как любые IF, так и любые циклы. Если некое условие соблюдается (Jxx) (или безусловно JMP) управление передается инструкции с определенным адресом и продолжается с той точки

Comment: Очень полезно Mike :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Типичный цикл на языке ассемблера (ассемблер для ARM в режиме Thumb, x86 я не знаю):

```
MOV  R6, 10 ; Здесь верхняя граница цикла
MOV  R5, 0 ; Регистр-счетчик, помещаем в него 0

; Это метка, она нужна для удобства программирования,
; когда ассемблер переведет этот код в инструкции процессора,
; он узнает его размер в байтах и, соответственно,
; фактический адрес этой метки и дальше в коде заменит его
nextItem:
; ...
; Здесь тело цикла
; ...

ADD  R5, 1 ; Увеличиваем значение в регистре-счетчике
CMP  R5, R6 ; Сравниваем значения регистров R5 и R6
BCC  nextItem ; Если меньше, переходим по адресу метки, иначе идем дальше (цикл завершается)

; На самом деле операция CMP вычитает из первого операнда второй,
; но не сохраняет результат, а только устанавливает соответствующие флаги,
; а операция BCC проверяет флаг C (Carry — флаг переноса) и выполняет переход
; если он сброшен
; но это не относится к вопросу, если интересно, можете почитать в литературе
```

Как вы видите, действительно никаких циклов среди инструкций процессора нет, он умеет только что-то вычислять и делать условные или безусловные переходы, если вы пишете код на языке ассемблера (или прямо в машинных кодах), то вы самостоятельно организовываете цикл (на самом деле вариаций цикла может быть куча и приведенный код — лишь одна из них), если вы пишете код на языке более высокого уровня, то за вас это делает компилятор или транслятор.